# How to pass parameter to asset from op in dagster

Tags: python-3.x, pipeline, orchestration, dagster

I am new to dagster and having difficult in running the asset for different parameter values when job scheduled.

I have created a pipeline using dagster.

Trying to materialize the outcome of upstream asset `multiple_num()` and using op to pass parameter value to the asset.

simplified example is

```
@asset
def get_a():
    return a
    
@asset 
def get_b():
    return b
    
@asset
def multiple_num(get_a, get_b):
    return c
    
@op
def get_values():
    values = ['a','s','e']
    for value in values:
        yield RunRequest(
            run_key=None,
            asset_selection = [AssetKey(multiple_num)]
        )
        cleanup_directory(value)

def cleanup_directory(): -> str
    return status
    
@job
def run_values():
   get_values()
```

Have to call the asset for different parameters values when job scheduled?

Comment: have you tried passing a parameter to the op? e.g. `get_values(multiple_num)`

Comment: I don't understand the use case. If you want to pass the values a,s,e to multiple_num at the end, only the e will be materialized as the previous values will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose the following solution using static partitions if all values should be materialized.

```
@asset
def get_a():
    return a


@asset
def get_b():
    return b


@asset(
    partitions_def=StaticPartitionsDefinition(["a", "s", "e"])
)
def multiple_num(context: AssetExecutionContext, get_a, get_b):
    partition_str = context.asset_partition_key_for_output()
    return c


@op
def get_values():
    yield RunRequest(
        asset_selection=[AssetKey(multiple_num)]
    )
    # clean-up


@job
def run_values():
    get_values()
```